# MACalendar-UI add event to empty cells

Tags: ios, user-interface, calendar, touch

I am new to IOS and trying to use this calendar UI: https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui

I would like to detect when user touches empty cells in the gridView in order to add events, has anyone tried it?

Thx